# Concat pandas dataframe combines out of order

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, concatenation

I am trying to combine a list of files into one dataframe in order to write it back out to a single csv. Each time I combine the files using pd.concat, everything completely reorders itself (both columns and rows) in the combined output file. My code is:

```
#create list of file paths
paths = []
for filepath in glob.iglob('pathtofiles'):
   paths.append(filepath)

#create list of dataframes to combine
df_list = []
for file in paths:
    df_list.append(pd.read_csv(file,header=0))

#combine all dataframes into single dataframe and output as csv
rebuild = pd.concat(df_list,  sort=True)
rebuild.to_csv('combined.csv',index=False)
```

The separate files have columns in the order ['time', 'name', 'quantity'] and are ordered by the ['time'] column. When I combine the files I want them to combine in order of the ['time'] column, but I get back a totally different order (ie. ['quantity','time','name'] ) and the files are out of order row-wise.

I think it has something to do with the fact that currently, the separate files' ['time'] columns are strings, and I believe they need to be datetime objects in order to combine properly, but I am unsure how to deal with this properly or if that is actually the issue.

[image]

Comment: I've encountered this before using `concat`, I kept columns in order by reordering them afterwards with `df.reindex(columns=columns_list)`. While I can't exactly explain what happened, I'll always do this instead of relying on `pd.concat` to return the correct order. Better be safe than sorry!

Comment: Can you provide a few rows of your data?

Comment: When you read the csv, set your time column to a datetime. There are args in read_csv to do this. Then when you write csv, leave the index.

Comment: @jeschward - I added a picture of the first few rows. I'm looking to order by the first column, 'time'

Answer (score 0):

Datetime Format issue:

If you look in the documentation for read_csv you can see that it has the argument "parse_dates". In order to tell pandas that your time column is datetime, you can read in the csv using below `pd.read_csv(file,header=0,parse_dates=['time'])`

Column Order Issue:

as Rocky already mentioned you can keep column order by using `df.reindex(columns=columns_list)` where column_list is the order you want the columns to be in.

Sorting by time column issue:

If you want to explicitly sort by the date column, you can change your `to_csv` to first sort it like this `rebuild.sort_values('time').to_csv('combined.csv',index=False)`